# User Rate Limit Exceeded Exception in Admin SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I am working with Admin SDK .when I update single user it's working fine but when I am trying to update bunch(1000) of users I got  **User Rate Limit Exceeded Exception**.      Please check below my code and tell me what am i missing ? or tell any suggestion ?

```
 private Directory getDirectoryService(String adminEmailAddress){
 Directory directoryService = null;
 try {
      Collection<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
      SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
      SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");
      SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group");
      SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly");
      SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit");
      SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly");
      SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
      GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
      .setServiceAccountUser(adminEmailAddress)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new                                                         java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH)).build();

    directoryService = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport,jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("gdirectoryspring").build();

 } catch(Exception e){
   ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getName(), e);
 }
 return directoryService;
}
```

**Below is Update User Code**

```
Directory directoryService = getDirectoryService("adminEmailAddress");
User user = directoryService.users().get("userPrimaryEmail").execute();
       List<UserOrganization> organizaionList = user.getOrganizations();
       for (int j = 0; j < organizaionList.size(); j++)
       {
         UserOrganization singleOrg = organizaionList.get(j);
         if (singleOrg != null)
         {
          if ("work".equalsIgnoreCase(singleOrg.getCustomType()) ||singleOrg.getPrimary() != null)  
  {
  if (singleOrg.getTitle() != null)
  { 
    singleOrg.setTitle(jobTitle);
   }
  }
 }
  user.setOrganizations(organizaionList);
}

       Update update= directoryService.users().update(primaryEmail, user);
       User userUpdated = update.execute();
```

and in admin console I increased my limit like below

```
Admin SDK   10.0 requests/second/user
```

but till I am getting **User Rate Limit Exceeded**  Excepiton. can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing exponential backoff.
See here for an example (its for drive but can be adapted)
https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff in there you will see how it deals with errors like 'userRateLimitExceeded'

Comment: dont know why this was marked down. its the correct answer. Hes getting an expected User Rate Limit Exceeded Excepiton because hes calling the api 1000s of times in a loop when his limit is 10 requests per second. He simply needs to handle the error and implmenent exponential backoff to retry the current element in the loop. he could also place "sleep" in key areas but that is not as generic and will wait more than needed.

Comment: I implemented the exponential back up now i am getting below error.<b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins><p>We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011490/token-response-exception

Comment: can u tell me any suggestion for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009892/status-code-503-requested-service-is-not-available-yet

Comment: I added exp backoff  , but getting same issues. Thread.sleep((1 << n) * 1000 + randomGenerator.nextInt(1001));