# Status Code 503, Requested service is not available yet

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using spring mvc(annotations). I have written backends. When tasks start running,
retry count goes on increasing, It shows status code '503' and message 'service unavailable'.
When I hit backend url into browser, I got the same error after hitting many times then getting correct response.

Is there any solution for this..?

Comment: how can we check, whether backend instance is available or not.? how much time it takes to start after deployment.?

Comment: First time, when i hit that backend url, It shows hard-dead-line error. any solution for that? I am using spring-annotations. After some time, If i start my backend then it works fine.